# The number comparison

Tags: grammar, word-choice, comparison, numbers

Which sentence is correct?

> Genies are six folds more than humans.
>
> Genies are six times more than humans.
>
> Genies are six times as many as humans.

Answer (score 2):

Both the second and third are grammatically and (potentially) semantically correct, depending on what quality or quantity the comparative seems to refer to. The first is actually grammatically correct as well, it's just semantically baffling (though enough context could make it work).

The third option suggests there are six times as many genie as there are humans; it is a comparison of strictly numerical quantity.

The second option is semantically incomplete. It needs either context or another word to be fully meaningful. "Genies are six times more **XXX** than humans" - what is the XXX? If you use *plentiful* or *numerous*, it means the same as the third option. Or you could use *powerful*, *handsome*, *intelligent*, *devious*.

The first option could be meaningful if context established that both genies and humans can be made by folding something, and it takes six more folds to make a genie. You may have been looking for the word *sixfold*, which means *six times* but needs different handling to that phrase, and is used in different ways. It can also mean *in six parts*.